# API for translating a U.S. state/territory abbreviation into full name

Tags: windows, library, software-development, api

I'm looking for an API that will translate U.S. state or territory abbreviations into full names.  I've seen plenty of "static" approaches to this where someone suggests just simply hard-coding a lookup, e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3925195/making-state-abbreviations-from-state-names), [this](https://brettdotnet.wordpress.com/2011/08/03/converting-state-abbreviations-and-names/), etc.

What I'm looking for, though, is an API that would be kept up-to-date as the U.S. acquires new territories (e.g. Northern Mariana Islands in 1978) or loses territories (e.g. Cuba in 1902).

I found the [USPS address information API](https://www.usps.com/business/web-tools-apis/address-information.htm), but that will only take a zip code and return a city/state abbreviation; it cannot be used to return the full state/territory name.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The USPS API has options that don't require a Zip code.  But I think it always returns the postal abbreviation.